# Can CSS set appropriate properties if a font exists?

Tags: css, fonts, exists

I would like to use different fonts in my web application. As their size are not equal, I want to do something in CSS like this pseudo-code:

```
if (exists(font1))
{
   font-size: 9pt; font-family: font1;
}
else
{
   font-size: 12pt; font-family: font2;
}
```

Is it possible? What's the best and correct solution for it?  How can I define font-size for a certain font and define another font-size for the next one ?

Comment: Are you trying to setup a conditional javascript statement that controls your CSS?

Comment: No I did not. Is it a good way ? How can I do it?

Comment: let me ask you this, when will font1 exist? You're gonna need some kind of ID or class or attribute existing on your page, ONLY when font1 is present on your page.

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS, and it's questionable whether or not it's worth doing with JavaScript.

Comment: User may install different fonts on his computer, but I don't know which fonts are installed. So I must call some fonts in `font-family` with attention to their orders

Comment: This is a good question due to how drastically fonts can differ even when their size is the same. I can't think of a CSS way to do it, however.

Comment: Exists where? Locally or on the server?

Comment: Absolutely locally. CSS loads fonts from the local machine by default

Comment: Have you looked at the standard recommended font stacks?  A lot of care has been put into developing these to ensure that only fonts of similar size/shape are used together when defining your element's font-family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS generally does not have conditions or other dynamic structures.

Your problem is solved through the use of so called "font stacks". You declare `font-family` with a list of comma separated fonts-names.  The client browser now picks the font from that list which he has available. That's why the creation of good font stacks is a tricky task (because they should look similar or at least have similar letter spacing / line-height). If you google for Web font stacks you will get some good articles about that topic from professional font-guys who already did the work for you creating nice font-stacks.

An alternative nowadays is to provide the font you want as  downloadable font via the `@font-face` declaration.  However keep in mind that:

- you need several formats to support all browsers
- they add additional weight to the page load which might be relevant for mobiles
- You need the right to use the font or use a free font (Google offers a service where you can pick from a variety of free fonts)

Comment: Should also note that custom font-faces should be used sparingly and avoid using for the majority of your text.  http://superuser.com/questions/547743/why-dont-websites-immediately-display-their-text-these-days

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript  statements for that.. or you can assign different id's for your text. For Eg:-

```
<div id="font1"><p>Some Text</p></div>
```

and then in your css file :-

```
#font1 p{
   font-family:sans-serif;
   font-size:10px;
}
```

so you can assign different fonts to different texts in your web application pretty well...

Comment: Which javascript conditional statements would the OP use in this case exactly?

Comment: i mean to say that create a div and assisgn id to it and then use document.getElementById("idname").style for changing fonts